# Show that $\left[\int_{0}^{1}f(x) \ dx\right]^2\geq\int_{0}^{1}(f(x))^3 \ dx$

Tags: calculus

Let $f$ be continous function with a continious derivative in $[0,1]$ such that $0<f'(x)<1$ and $f(0)=0.$ Show that $$\left[\int_{0}^{1}f(x) \ dx\right]^2\geq\int_{0}^{1}(f(x))^3 \ dx.$$

I apologize for not having an attempt. Many times I learn the best by observing whole solutions and asking question about them.

Comment: My (admittedly small) education in learning psychology leads me to understand that almost anyone would learn even better by trying something first, get stuck, then get help. It's just that that takes a bit more effort, so it's tempting to skip, both for learner and teacher. For instance, have you considered proving something analoguous for sums rather than integrals? Or changing the upper bound form $1$ to $t$, and differentiating with respect to $t$? I don't know whether any of these lead to a solution, but to me they're obvious things I would try before declaring myself stuck.

Comment: I find that I get in better shape by watching other people do push-ups.  It just gives me a better sense of well-being than attempting them myself.

Comment: @ Arthur: Indeed I usually try very hard before I ask for help. I'm on vacation now and this is just a contest problem that I wan't able to solve. Me and a few other similar minded just thorw random math questions to eachother, so my aim here is not to learn math in order to ace a test or something. I also believe that others here find it ammusing to post full solutions. I do when there is a problem I know how to solve.

Comment: @ B. Goddard: That comparason is very bad. You can't compare something theoretical with something practical like that. Read my comment above.

Comment: @Arthur, now I wonder whether this result is related to $ (\sum n)^2 = \sum n^3$.

Comment: @Parseval "wasn't able to solve" would imply you made an attempt yet the OP clearly states "I apologize for having no  attempt." Which is it?

Comment: @Parseval People don't post their attempt here because they find it "amusing". They do it because that is a rule of this site. You could read [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) to know more. When you go buy something, you pay for it. So, when you ask a question here, you post an "attempted" solution in return of help. Why should people try to solve your problems for you if even you're not willing to do it for yourself?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We first note that $f(0)=0$ and $f'\geq 0$ imply that for $t\in [0,1]$
$$f(t)=\int_0^t f'(t)dt\geq 0.$$
For $t\in [0,1]$ consider the function
$$H(t):=\left[\int_{0}^{t}f(x) \ dx\right]^2-\int_{0}^{t}(f(x))^3 \ dx$$
Since $H(0)=0$, it suffices to show that $H$ is increasing. Then $H(1)\geq H(0)=0$ and the required inequality holds.

By taking the derivative, we have that
$$H'(t)=2f(t)\int_{0}^{t}f(x) \ dx-f^3(t)=f(t)\left(2\int_{0}^{t}f(x) \ dx-f^2(t)\right).$$
Hence $H$ is increasing iff for $t\in [0,1]$,
$$G(t):=2\int_{0}^{t}f(x) \ dx-f^2(t)\geq 0.$$
Since $f(0)=0$, we have that $G(0)=0$. Moreover $f'\leq 1$ and $f\geq 0$ implies that
$$G'(t):=2f(t) \ dx-2f(t)f'(t)=2f(t)(1-f'(t))\geq 0.$$
Hence $G$ is increasing and $G(t)\geq G(0)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

You may first show it to be hold for $f(x)=ax^n$ for arbitrary $n$ and a proper $a$ which satisfies the conditions, and then you can conclude the result for a continuous function.